# ms access query to create a new login id, each time i wish to add a new user through a user details form

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, vb6, stack-overflow

I have a Login table containing user information like, login id, username, password and access level. So i created a form called user details form where i can add new users into the database.

each time i open the user details form, a new id is generated by running a query.

this is what i typed in the field of the query to generate a new id,

`new_login_ID: "LI" & Right([Login_ID],2)+1`

the problem is, in my login form, i try to login with the following code:

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click()

'Check to see if data is entered into the UserName combo box

Dim lngMyEmpID As Long

If IsNull(Me.cboEmployee) Or Me.cboEmployee = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a User Name.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.cboEmployee.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

lngMyEmpID = Me.cboEmployee.Value

'Check to see if data is entered into the password box

If IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Or Me.txtPassword = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check value of password in tblAdmins to see if this matches value chosen in combo box

If Me.txtPassword.Value <> DLookup("Password", "tbl_login", "[Login_ID]=" & lngMyEmpID) Then

            MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
            Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
            Me.txtPassword = Null
            intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
            'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown
            If intLogonAttempts >= 3 Then
                MsgBox "You do not have access to this database. Please contact your system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
                Application.Quit
            End If

Else
    Me.txtPassword = Null
    'Open correct form
    Dim strAccessLevel As String

    strAccessLevel = DLookup("[Access]", "tbl_login", "[Login_ID]=" & lngMyEmpID)

    If strAccessLevel = "Admin" Then

        MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("Username", "tbl_login", "Login_ID=" & lngMyEmpID)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Admin"

    ElseIf strAccessLevel = "Manager" Then
        'MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("Username", "tbl_login", "Login_ID")
        MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("Username", "tbl_login", "Login_ID=" & lngMyEmpID)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_main_menu"
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

I get a runtime error saying "mismatch" and when i debug, it points to this line of my login code - `lngMyEmpID = Me.cboEmployee.Value`

I dont know how to fix this, can someone please explain where i've gone wrong and how i can fix this problem.. thanks in advance :)

Comment: what data are you trying to enter in `Me.cboEmployee.Value` ? It's a UserName? Does it contains only digits? If no, try to change line `Dim lngMyEmpID As Long` to `Dim lngMyEmpID As String`

Comment: i changed the line `Dim lngMyEmpID As Long` to `Dim LngMyEmpID As String`, now it points to this line of the code when i debug, `If Me.txtPassword.Value <> DLookup("Password", "tbl_login", "[Login_ID]=" & lngMyEmpID)` , do i have to change something in this line? i cant seem to figure out how to fix this, please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would be wise to rename lngMyEmpID to strMyEmpID for a start to make the code more consistent and intuitive for others, given that it's now a string. Secondly, I'd check whether the line which gets the value from the combo box returns a string or a number. And finally, check your Login_ID field in the table is consistent with this: string or number? If string then you need to have a single quote before and after the value being used as criteria in the Dlookup

Comment: the table login_ID field is set to "text", i also changed the lngMyEmpID to strMyEmpID. Still no luck, is there a way to change my query field where i have this `new_login_ID: "LI" & Right([Login_ID],2)+1`. how do i change this? For instance, i dont want the "LI" instead just have numbers only, how do i make the changes to this code?

Answer (score 0):

This line you have written in the comments should be corrected to this (since lngMyEmpID is now a string) :

```
If Me.txtPassword.Value <> DLookup("Password", "tbl_login", "[Login_ID]='" & lngMyEmpID & "'")
```

Same goes for every line you use DLookup and the ID in this manner.